# How to filter FormGroup values?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a massive FormGroup, it has many FormControls and many nested FormArrays, and i need to get the value of the top FormGroup except some controls. These controls may be situated very deep in nested FormArrays

Is there any angular way to filter form_group.value or form_group.getRawValue()?

Comment: Basically you'll have to iterate over controls and filter it based on your condition as any other object.

Comment: @developer033, so no built in function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no built in function for that, so I had to implement some functions that manually collect values:

```
getFormValue(form_group: FormGroup): any {
  const value = {};

  Object.keys(form_group.controls).forEach(control_name => {
    if (/* condition that shows that the value should not be filtered out */) {
      value[control_name] = this.getFormItemValue(form_group.controls[control_name]);
    }
  });

  return value;
}

getFormItemValue(item: AbstractControl): any {
  if (item instanceof FormControl) {
    return item.value;
  } else if (item instanceof FormArray) {
    return item.controls.map(form_group => {
      return this.getFormValue(form_group as FormGroup);
    });
  } else if (item instanceof FormGroup) {
    return this.getFormValue(item as FormGroup);
  }
}
```